# Array filled with recursive function is only containing the numbers from n to half of n but not to 0

Tags: arrays, typescript, recursion

I want to fill the array with a recursive function. The returned array is not containing like actually desired all numbers from n to 0 but from n to its half, why? I can not figure it out.

```
let fillArrayBackwards = (n : number, a : number[]) : number[] =>{
    a.push(n);
    return a.length <= n ? fillArrayBackwards(--n, a) : a;
} 

console.log(fillArrayBackwards(10,[]));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your condition `a.length <= n`. You are decrementing `n`, and adding elements to `a`, so at some point, `n` will be less than the length of `a`, about halfway through.

Change your condition to `n > 0`, like this:

```
let fillArrayBackwards = (n: number, a: number[]): number[] => {
    a.push(n);
    return n > 0 ? fillArrayBackwards(--n, a) : a;
} 

console.log(fillArrayBackwards(10,[]));
```

That will return:
`[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`